# Nonmeasurable sets.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying Lebesgue integration with Frank Jones's book that goes step by step and I found a proposed problem about nonmeasurable sets that says:

Prove that if A and B are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ wich are "separated" in the sense that there exists a measurable set $C$ such that 
$$A \subset C \quad and \quad \lambda(B \cap C)=0,$$

then

$$\lambda^* (A \cup B)= \lambda^* (A) + \lambda^* (B).$$

So I'm trying to use this property:

$A$ is measurable $\Leftrightarrow$  for every set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ 
$\lambda^* (E) =  \lambda^* (E \cap A) + \lambda^* (E \cap A^{c})$

Here $\lambda^*$ is the ***outer measure*** and it is defined as: $$\lambda^*(A)=inf\left\{ \lambda(G) \mid A \subset G= open \quad set \right\}$$

I guess the best idea I have until know (actually is not even a good idea because I don't even know how to start) is trying to set the $E$ of the property as $E=A \cup B$ and try to fit something like 
$$\lambda^* (A \cup B) = \lambda^*((A \cup B) \cap C) + \lambda^*((A \cup B) \cap C^{c})$$

And I tried to something with this but I don't seem to get near to the answer and I don't really know how to start or anything. Please guys help me with this, I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did the good thing, now you need to use :

$$\lambda^*(S\cup T)\leq \lambda^*(S)+\lambda^*(T) $$

So that $\lambda^*((A\cup B)\cap C)\leq \lambda^*(A\cap C)+\lambda^*(B\cap C)=\lambda^*(A)$. Now clearly $A\subseteq (A\cup B)\cap C$ so :

$$\lambda^*(A)=\lambda^*((A\cup B)\cap C) $$

The same idea will apply to to the other side to show that $\lambda^*((A\cup B)\cap C^c)=\lambda^*(B)$.